# php mysql query search with 2 parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code

```
 $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM iptable 
               WHERE user_id = '$userid_c' AND ip = '$ip' LIMIT 0, 30 ";
 $query5=mysql_query($sql5);
 $row_ip_a = mysql_num_rows($query5);
```

When I use this from phpmyadmin it returns fine results but when I use it from php it always returns one row.

What could be the reason?

Comment: did you try without the LIMIT?

Comment: Beware of [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) ;)

Comment: More details, please!
What is in your variables? What is in your database? Are those variables assigned correctly?

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the row returned in php? Is it correct as is, just that the rest of the rows are missing? If so, does it consistently return the same row, e.g., the first from the set returned by phpMyAdmin? What happens if you change the LIMIT clause?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I'm guessing you are not using variables, but static values, when testing in phpMyAdmin? Have you tried the _exact_ same query in php, i.e., replacing the variables with static values?

Comment: just var_dump your $sql5 and try that in phpmyadmin. Better yet, use a mysql client.  As small friendly tip, you should [look into sprintf](http://www.talkphp.com/general/1062-securing-your-mysql-queries-sprintf.html) for your queries, it is well worth the added security layer.

Comment: What collation do you use in your connection?

Comment: Its deafult  everything is deafult

Comment: Anyways can u guys put a tested one with 2 parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_num_rows — Get number of rows in result

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";?>
```

U need this:
**mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both**

Your Code Just Yields with number of rows affected, 
where as u need the data from select query

hence You can use mysql_fetch_array as:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```

Comment: I dont get it or u didnt got what I meant. In short what I want is get the no. of rows in query "which matches 2 values"

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data set, it's hard to see whether you're getting the same results.

Assuming that when you put it in PHPMyAdmin, you fill out `$userid_c` and `$ip` with manual values?  Try plugging in these manual values instead of the variables above, and see whether that works (if it does, then there's a problem with your variables).